# Create scalable Three Line Menu Nav-icon for button in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, vector, uibutton, icons

How can I make my button scalable? Programmatically, using vector or something else?  It is just a typical navigation icon with triple lines. Is there a simple way to create crisp, scalable icon without using images?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too broad, could you show us what you tried so far ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can make UIView containing UILable and make it like navigation bar button by setting it's background color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can create the icons using Core Graphics. Please follow these simple 4 steps to draw 3 bar button icon.

1) Add `UIButton` to your storyboard and place it.
[image]

2) Create Cocoa Class of base class UIButton name it like 'NavButton' 
   and paste following code
[image]

```
import UIKit

class NavButton: UIButton {


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // thickness of your line
    let lineThick:CGFloat = 1.0

    // length of your line relative to your button
    let lineLenght:CGFloat = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) * 0.8

    // color of your line
    let lineColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // this will add small padding from button border to your first line and other lines
    let marginGap: CGFloat = 5.0

    // we need three line
    for line in 0...2 {
        // create path
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.lineWidth = lineThick

        //start point of line
        linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(
            x: bounds.width/2 - lineLenght/2,
            y: 6.0 * CGFloat(line) + marginGap
            ))

        //end point of line
        linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
            x: bounds.width/2 + lineLenght/2,
            y: 6.0 * CGFloat(line) + marginGap
            ))
        //set line color
        lineColor.setStroke()

        //draw the line
        linePath.stroke()
    }


    }


}
```

3) Assing `NavButton` class to your `UIButton` from Identity Inspector >  Custom Class > Class field
[image]

4) Remove default title of your button from  Attribute Inspector > Default Title (fourth one)
[image]

Done, Now build and run you can see your button with bars
[image]

Comment: of course it is scalable it uses core graphic paths and fills, it is vector.

Answer (score 0):

Updating [@KamaalABOOTHALIB's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411572/create-scalable-three-line-menu-nav-icon-for-button-in-swift-2#34411733) for Swift 3:

```
import UIKit

class NavButton: UIButton {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    // thickness of your line
    let lineThick:CGFloat = 1.0

    // length of your line relative to your button
    let lineLength:CGFloat = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) * 0.8

    // color of your line
    let lineColor: UIColor = UIColor.black

    // this will add small padding from button border to your first line and other lines
    let marginGap: CGFloat = 5.0

    // we need three line
    for line in 0...2 {
        // create path
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.lineWidth = lineThick

        //start point of line
        linePath.move(to: CGPoint(
            x: bounds.width/2 - lineLength/2,
            y: 6.0 * CGFloat(line) + marginGap
        ))

        //end point of line
        linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(
            x: bounds.width/2 + lineLength/2,
            y: 6.0 * CGFloat(line) + marginGap
        ))
        //set line color
        lineColor.setStroke()

        //draw the line
        linePath.stroke()
    }

}
```