# What is the correct way to get a three lines menu navigation button item

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a navigation button bar item like this. I wonder what is the right way to get it because I don't see this kind of button in Bar Button Item.

I've read this [following topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411572/create-scalable-three-line-menu-nav-icon-for-button-in-swift-2) to draw it by code, but I don't know if that way is appropriate or there're some different way to get it? because I know that I can get it by making an item of it

[image]

Comment: Create or obtain an image from somewhere and use it on your button

Comment: It's called a hamburger icon for your searching reference.

Comment: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/134216/hamburger_lines_menu_icon :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally belive that correct way is to not implement such kind of menu in iOS. I want to make myself clear - I do such a thing by myself as per the customer desire, i know how to do that and how it works.

In the meanwhile UI should be consistent for positive user experience. Users should not be confused by the UI of your app. Take a look at the applications iOS users have from scratch (Calendar, Mail, Notes, etc..). Does any of them have such kind of menu? It came from the Android holo-design, and widely used in the Android, but, in my humble opinion, should be avoided in the iOS.

Anyway, since there is no 'right'-way to do that, implement the easiest one - just take an appropriate image, and put it into the Bar-Item.

Comment: Aleksandr I couldn't agree more. But I should mention why no iOS application have this "hamburger" button. Because iOS (and Apple) logic is, that user should always know what will any action do, before do it. Thats why they have very descriptive buttons that tell users what will happened when he will click on it. Even in popup messages you should avoid just Ok, Cancel paradigma, but tell user what Ok or Cancel mean. With the same logic, hamburger menu hide all options from the user, and user can't be sure what lays beneath this button. Thats is why Apple don't recommend using it.

Comment: this is a very poor answer. It's a lecture based on bias with no grounding in the real world. All humans require "Standard GUI Controls" to help the user manage the interface. The rampant "Guessing at language empty, unqualified images" is a huge issue with all products... ESPECIALLY mobile apps.. it's a lazy way to avoid having to work in geo-specific confines.. a lazy way to avoid words.. and it's sloppy disrespectful and suboptimal.. (for example there isn't a LITERATE human on earth who can't understand "OK", "BACK" or "GO" whatever the language).. and YES this is the hamburger argument

Comment: hamburger menus are standard gui controls that allow top level navigation.. that's what they mean all users know it.. instead you prefer to dream a little dream about a world that isn't here. all the while using paper airplane icons, and tick icons, and tap and hold.. because it's cheap and makes you feel suave when you stare at it all day - mate most people make decisions in 0.3 seconds.. if you can't identify something's purpose in 0.3 you will abort and seek another route ..this is a human principle of "maximum perceived affordance".. so when they can't figure out ur gui they need hamburger

Answer (score 0):

Download icon from https://icons8.com/web-app/for/ios7/menu saved it to your project assets and named is as hamburger

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "hamburger.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.callMethod), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```